# How to change the version of Ruby in a Docker image (replace 2.2.0 with 2.0.0 )

Tags: ruby, heroku, docker

The Heroku Docker image heroku/ruby installs ruby 2.2.3.

How do I use that image, but use ruby 2.0.0 instead (trying to Dockerize a Rails 3.2 app).

I know that the location of the Heroku buildpack for 2.0.0 is

```
https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.amazonaws.com/cedar-14/ruby-2.0.0.tgz
```

but cannot see how to modify my Dockerfile so that it will use that version of Ruby instead.

I tried:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM heroku/ruby

# Install Ruby
ONBUILD RUN curl -s --retry 3 -L https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.amazonaws.com/cedar-14/ruby-2.0.0.tgz | tar xz -C /app/heroku/ruby/ruby-2.2.0
```

which I'd hoped might overwrite the 2.2.0 with 2.0.0 (keeping the path etc the same) but that command gets ignored when I run `docker-compose build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing (ruby and node) on the same docker file reproducing heroku environment:

```
FROM heroku/heroku:16

# Ruby dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential\
    libpq-dev\
    libxml2-dev\
    libxslt1-dev\
    nodejs\
    npm \
    qt5-default\
    libqt5webkit5-dev\
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base\
    gstreamer1.0-tools\
    gstreamer1.0-x\
    xvfb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Ruby heroku
RUN apt remove -y --purge ruby && curl -s --retry 3 -L https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-16/ruby-2.3.4.tgz | tar -xz

# Node heroku
RUN export NODE_VERSION=6.11.0 && \
  curl -s --retry 3 -L https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /tmp/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
  tar -xzf /tmp/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
  rsync -a /tmp/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/ / && \
  rm -rf /tmp/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64*

WORKDIR /var/app
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build an image yourself with the right versions. Change this Dockerfile as necessary - https://github.com/heroku/docker-ruby/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Also needed is the init.sh file in the local directory used to hold the Dockerfile which is at https://github.com/heroku/docker-ruby/blob/master/init.sh